# What is the best way to delete unique values from Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 5 text file datasets loaded as Pandas Dataframe (data1, data2, ..., data 5; each are mx2 columns: SSID, RSSI).

Typical Dataset looks like this (written using `pd.DataFrame` for the sake of reproducible example):

```python
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', -70], ['B', -65], ['C', -55]], columns=['SSID', 'RSSI'])
```

My main goal is to find the average RSSI value of each duplicated SSID found in all 5 measurement dataset.

But first, I want to remove all the rows with unique SSID (i.e. SSID value does **NOT** occur in ALL 5 datasets)

I have tried using the `pd.duplicated` method by concatenating the first 2 datasets:

```python
frames1 = [data1, data2]
df1 = pd.concat(frames1)
```

Then, removing all the unique SSIDs:

```python
dupes1 = df1[df1.duplicated('SSID') | df1.duplicated('SSID', keep='last')]
```

However, when I try to do the same thing again for the remaining datasets, the number of rows in the duplicated Dataframe `dupes` keeps increasing instead of eventually converging to the same number.

```python
frames2 = [dupes1,data3]
df2 = pd.concat(frames2)
dupes2 = df2[df2.duplicated('SSID') | df2.duplicated('SSID', keep='last')]
```

Is there a better way to remove unique values from multiple dataframes?

Edit: I found out that the method I posted worked well for ONLY 2 datasets. The number of rows kept adding up because `concat()` also concatenate:

1. Any missing values (NaN) due to row numbers may be different for each data set
2. Any duplicate row with SSID value existing in dataset > 2

Comment: Please revise your question to include your data as text, not images.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `sets` to perform an intersect operation, then filtering all your DataFrames using the intersection? Something like...

```
dfs = [data1, data2, data3, data4, data5]
SSID_sets = [set(df['SSID']) for df in dfs]
duplicated_SSIDs = set.intersection(*SSID_sets)
dfs_filtered = [df[df['SSID'].isin(duplicated_SSIDs)] for df in dfs]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your method on Jupyter and it just shows empty dataframes in my output

Comment: Weird. I updated the code slightly, but looks like you found your solution!

Comment: I tested your updated code and it seems to be have working more efficiently than mine as well as solved the problems I have with missing values. Thank you!